# How do we install Alienvault's OSSIM in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alienvault

Is there any process to install Alienvault's OSSIM in AWS apart from importing VM to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way of installing this on AWS other than the VM way.